# RROR [ restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm getting the below error while running my springboot application

```
2024-03-03T22:59:00.898+05:30  INFO 11404 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-03-03T22:59:00.913+05:30  INFO 11404 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-03T22:59:00.943+05:30 ERROR 11404 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Entity 'com.codewithshivam.blog.entities.Category' has no identifier (every '@Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at com.codewithshivam.blog.BlogAppApisApplication.main(BlogAppApisApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Entity 'com.codewithshivam.blog.entities.Category' has no identifier (every '@Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.InheritanceState.postProcess(InheritanceState.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.handleIdentifier(EntityBinder.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.bindEntityClass(EntityBinder.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:256) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tired changing the port still no luck.

Comment: I found the solution for above problem by entering import jakarta.persistence.Id;

Comment: Nice @Shivam! I'm glad you resolved the issue. It would have been better to also add the `com.codewithshivam.blog.entities.Category` Class so that we would have also seen the issue also within the `Category` entity Class.